# Deleting Events with Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

**Reference:** https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

**Errors**: *Missing name after . operator. (line 131, file "Code")*

```
function deleteEvent() {

  for (var i = 1; i < datalastRow; i++) {

    var calendarId = sheet.getRange('E2').getValue();

    var delete_eventid = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).getValue()

      var params = {
        calendarId: calendarId,
        eventId: delete_eventid,
      };

      calendar.events.delete(params, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Event deleted.');
      });

  }

}
```

Basically the line `calendar.events.delete(params, function(err)) {` is throwing an error when I attempt to save the code, I am unsure why this is happening as I can run `calendar.events.insert` and create events just fine, but it appears to not like `calendar.events.delete`.

Edit: I removed the extra ")" as referenced in the first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Google Apps Script, how about this? You can delete events by [deleteEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#deleteEvent()). deleteEvent() returns void. So I used try-catch for this.

```
function deleteEvent() {
  var calendarId = sheet.getRange('E2').getValue();
  for (var i = 1; i < datalastRow; i++) {
    var delete_eventid = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).getValue();
    try {
      CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getEventById(delete_eventid).deleteEvent();
    } catch(e) {
      console.error("Error deleting event " + delete_eventid + " from calendar " + calendarId + ". Error: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on this line:

```
calendar.events.delete(params, function(err)) {
```

The second parameter to delete should be a function, but it should look like this:

```
calendar.events.delete(params, function(err) { ... })
```

The difference being that the second `)` wraps the callback.

Comment: I removed the extra ")" but still get the same error.